# Stuck showing uniform boundedness of a subset in C[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

My problem is as follows:

*Let E be a bounded subset in C[0,1]. Prove the set of all functions F(x) = $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ with f $\in$ E is relatively compact in C[0,1].*

Now I know I need to use the Ascoli-Arzela theorem, and I have already shown the set is equicontinuous. However, I am stuck on showing the set is uniformly bounded in C[0,1] and would greatly appreciate a helpful hint.

The definition of uniformly bounded I'm working with is as follows: A $\subset$ C[a,b] is uniformly bounded if there exists a constant C > 0 such that |f(x)| $\leq$ C $\forall$f$\in$A, $\forall$x$\in$[0,1].

How can I show that one of the bounds on the functions in my set E must be a bound on all other functions?

Comment: If $|f|\le C$, then $|F(x)|\le \int_0^x C ds\le C$.

Comment: This has done it. I was not thinking clearly, thank you very much for your help.